# Which operation is fast for iterator to sequence conversion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I had to convert an iterator to a subscriptable sequence (eg. list, tuple). Now when I tried to do so I stumbled upon two options to accomplish that. The question is now which one is the most recommended and fast?

Use the constructor of `tuple` or `list` to convert.

```py
percents = range(100+1)

tuple(percents)  # to a tuple.
list(percents)   # to a list.
```

Use unpacking in `tuple` or `list` comprehension.

```
[*percents]   # to a list.
(*percents,)  # to a tuple.
```

Comment: Which one runs fastest for your application?  Use `timeit` to run some experiments.

Comment: The canonical way is to use the `list` or `tuple` constructors. I have never seen unpacking used solely to evaluate a generator.

Comment: The generator was just an example because it's very similar to an iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, the answer isn't the same for lists and tuples (that is, running on Python 3.8 on my specific machine - depending on where your code runs and what version of Python is used, your mileage may vary):

```
from timeit import timeit

percents = range(100+1)


def construct_tuple():
    tuple(percents)


def unpack_into_tuple():
    return *percents,


def construct_list():
    list(percents)


def unpack_into_list():
    return [*percents]


print(timeit(construct_tuple, number=1000000))
print(timeit(unpack_into_tuple, number=1000000))
print(timeit(construct_list, number=1000000))
print(timeit(unpack_into_list, number=1000000))
```

Results:

```
0.48456099999999996
0.5760516999999999
0.4818578
0.3919844000000001
```

This remains the same for larger iterables.

Now, *why* unpacking is faster for lists, but slower for tuples, I cannot tell you. It may have to do with the way the list comprehension deals with its parameter vs the tuple comprehension. It's striking that both constructor functions are very comparable, while the comprehension of `unpack_into_tuple()` is much slower than the comprehension of `unpack_into_list()`

Your question was which is "the recommended and fast". I'd say all of them are fast, so the recommended option should really be the one that's most readable and maintainable in your code.

If this is a key part of your code that gets executed millions of times, you may care about speed - but you have to wonder if Python is the best choice. You're probably best off picking the option that reads most clearly, to others and your future self.

Answer (score 0):

i try it, and they are so close

```
import timeit
percents = range(100+1)
timeit.timeit('tuple(percents)', number=10000, setup="from __main__ import percents")
timeit.timeit('list(percents)', number=10000, setup="from __main__ import percents")
timeit.timeit('(*percents,)', number=10000, setup="from __main__ import percents")
timeit.timeit('[*percents]', number=10000, setup="from __main__ import percents")
```

you could try it